# Difference between Syscall and Traps

Tags: exception, mips, system-calls, mips32

I am wondering if there is any difference between the MIPS syscall and trap instructions. I can't find anything involving this, so I am not sure if there is a difference. Traps seem to just be a conditional syscall, but some clarifying can be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SYSCALL` and `TRAP` instructions both trigger exceptions, but the resulting exception is of a different type (SystemCall versus Trap), and the operating system will likely handle them differently.

Comment: What do operating systems usually use traps for?

Comment: Typically, they don't. On most systems I've used, traps will just crash the process which triggers them, the same as most other CPU exceptions.

Comment: Should I just make it a conditional system call then to save some code when you possibly may need a system call.

Comment: Yes. You almost always need to do a bunch of setup surrounding a system call anyway, so it's not as though being able to make a system call conditional would do you much good.

Answer (score 2):

A `Trap` is an exception switches to kernel mode by invoking a kernel sub-routine (any [system call)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). Usually trap creates any kind of control transfer to operating system. Where as `SYSCALL` is synchronous and planned user process to kernel mode.