# What is the difference between system call and trap?

Tags: linux, operating-system, system-calls

I searched before I asked a question and found this post.
[Difference between Syscall and Traps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004766/difference-between-syscall-and-traps)

`But this is not clear to me.`
Many books explain syscall and trap at once.
In another book said, syscall is a kind of trap.

Someone says that they generate a trap through a syscall, which causes chaos for me.

Aren't both syscall and trap are software interrupts?

I understood that the program need something but It can only work in kernel mode.
So requests syscall and through the trap the operating system takes the cpu.

> It is obvious that interrupts occur during the first syscall.
>   But interrupt occur again during the trap phase after syscall? I'm confused.

Comment: This could be different for different architectures - could you clarify which one you have in mind (and add the corresponding tag to your question)?

Comment: I thank you for your interest.
I studying about the architecture of a Linux operating system.

Comment: I mean, which CPU architecture?  [Linux runs on many.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux-supported_computer_architectures)  x86-32, x86-64, ARM, MIPS, SPARC, etc, etc...?

Comment: Oops, sorry. `x86-32.`  
I am studying the operating system for the first time and reading an introductory book.  
And almost all of the books are described as x86-32.